# When running cell in Vscode Jupyter I get : 'NameError: name 'dataloader' is not defined.'

Tags: import, anaconda, conda, virtualenv, vscode-extensions

These are the imports required:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
%matplotlib inline
from PIL import Image
from IPython.display import display
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision import datasets, transforms, models
from torch.optim.lr_scheduler import StepLR
from torchsummary import summary
from tqdm import tqdm
```

The following: `image`, `torch`, `nn`, `DataLoader`, `models`, `StepLR`, `tqdm` are "greyed out".
Mouse over gives : "X" is not accessed Pylance. Running the cell however gives a `success` sign.
I have created a virtual environment in conda, activated the proper Kernel in vscode jupyter notebook.
When I reach the following cell ( I have omitted the rest ):

```
train_loader = dataloader(train_data, batch_size=16, shuffle=True, pin_memory=True)           
test_loader = dataloader(test_data, batch_size=1, shuffle=False, pin_memory=True)
```

I get: `NameError: name 'dataloader' is not defined`
I have to mention this is the first time I am doing all this. My guess, the imports are not loaded properly.

I have created and tried; a python 10 env, a python 3.6 env and installed (manually) all required packages.
Things like `Image`, `torch`, `dataloader`, `models`, `StepLR`, `tqdm`, I can't see when I do `conda list`, so I am guessing they are parts of a package.
How would I work from here, I am at a loss. Thank you.

Comment: Apparently, it was a simple Type error. I used `dataloader` while the import was  `DataLoader`.